# How to validate algorithm ant colony optimization vs parallelism ant colony optimization for reduction of dimensionality

Tags: parallel-processing, dimensionality-reduction, ant-colony

I am using the ant colony algorithm for the reduction of dimensionality, and I am going to compare it with an ant colony algorithm but parallel. My question is, what type of database should I use??? and as valid these algorithms???. Help please, it is to present in a paper.

Comment: What is the algorithm/approach for using ACO for DR?

Comment: Is for reduction of dimensionality